# why there is a difference between GPS time to date

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have some trouble decoding the `Date(1561525200000-0500)` into a readable date.
It should be `10-10-2017`.
I use python.

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1561525200000/1000)
```

The result is

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 26, 5, 0)
```

I don't know what is the problem. There is difference between expected and real dates.

So what is this date format? Is there any format not GPS time but works?
I already found some but nothing works.
It drives me crazy.

Comment: The `fromtimestamp` method assumes the input is POSIX seconds since the epoch (UNIX time) - are you sure that this is the case? Also, your input seems to have a UTC offset - I suggest you parse that correctly and set it as `tzinfo` instead of using `utcfromtimestamp` - [this method does evil](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html) ;-)

Comment: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php shows that the datetime from python is correct. Probably the timestamp is in different format.

Answer (score 0):

here's a way how you could parse the UTC offset - split on the sign of the offset and parse accordingly:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

datestring = '1561525200000-0500'

parts = re.split('(\+|\-)', datestring)

if len(parts) > 1:
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(parts[0])/1e3,
                                tz=timezone(timedelta(hours=int(''.join(parts[1:])[:3]),
                                                      minutes=int(parts[-1][2:]))))
else: # string contains no UTC offset...
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(parts[0])/1e3, tz=timezone.utc)

# dt
# datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400)))
```

Comment: yeah, here is the thing. It should not be 2019-06-26. It should be 2017-10-10, so that is the reason I ask. It seems not like the normal GPS time.

Comment: I checked the same record in RDBS it showed 2017-10-10, but when I calculated the date in the JSON file it is 2019-06-26.

Comment: @Lauren-Shen: seems like your numbers aren't Posix seconds since the epoch. Do you have data from other periods of time so you can check if the offset vs. Unix time changes over the years?

Comment: It is weird. I found 2018-08-01 in RDBM  /Date(1403240400000-0500)/ in the JSON and 2017-10-10 in RDBM /Date(1561525200000-0500)/ in the JSON

Comment: @Lauren-Shen: that seems weird indeed. The difference to POSIX seconds changes from negative to positive within less than a year...

Comment: Yes. It has a negative value, so it is impossible to be a difference from the current time.